# A question on group isomorphism between $(\Bbb{R},+) $ and $(\Bbb{C}, +) $ .

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces, group-isomorphism

$(\Bbb{R},+) $ and $(\Bbb{C}, +) $ are group-isomorphic.

Consider, two vector space $\Bbb{R}_{\Bbb{Q}}$ and $\Bbb{C}_{\Bbb{Q}}$.

Any two vector space over the same field having same dimension are linearly isomorphic.

Suppose, $T: \Bbb{R}_{\Bbb{Q}}\to \Bbb{C}_{\Bbb{Q}}$ be an Invertible linear map.

And the additive structure are group isomorphic.

Question :

1. Is the above way is correct?
2. I know that $\Bbb{R}_{\Bbb{Q}}$ and $\Bbb{C}_{\Bbb{Q}}$ are infinite dimensional vector space but how to find the cardinality of their hamel basis or how to prove their respective basis have the same cardinality?

Comment: No, this is not enough. You need to show your claim. Your proof should more look like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/302514/are-mathbbr-and-mathbbc-isomorphic-as-additive-groups) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337084/are-the-groups-mathbbc-and-mathbbr-isomorphic) at the duplicates.

Comment: Since C is obviously isomorphic to R x R as additive groups, it's enough to argue that R is infinite dimensional over Q and that the product of an infinite cardinal M with itself is M.