# Which of the following groups are isomorphic (TIFR 2014)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Which of the following groups are isomorphic?

(a) $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$

(b) $\mathbb{R}^*$ and $\mathbb{C}^*$

(c) $S_3\times \mathbb{Z}_4$ and $S_4$

(d) $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}_4$

Here option (d) is not correct because one is not cyclic and other one is cyclic. Also $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ are vector space isomorphic (over the field $\mathbb{Q}$). But i cannot conclude correct answer help me!

Comment: What is TIFR 2014?

Comment: @Gerry_Myerson it seems to be an entrance exam to the tata institute of mathematical research. I was able to find it here: http://univ.tifr.res.in/gs2015/Prev_QP/Prev_QP.htm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(a) As you have observed, these are isomorphic as $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces. *A fortiori* their underlying additive groups are isomorphic.

(b) Count the solutions of $x^4=1$ in $\mathbb{R}^*$ resp. $\mathbb{C}^*$. (Alternatively, look at the map $x \mapsto x^2$ and check for surjectivity.)

(c) The abelianization of $S_3 \times \mathbb{Z}/4$ is $\mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/4$, but the abelianization of $S_4$ is $\mathbb{Z}/2$. (Alternatively, notice that there is no epimorphism $S_4 \to \mathbb{Z}/4$ since the kernel would contain the commutator subgroup $A_4$, but it would have only $4!/4=6$ elements.)

(d) You are right, $\mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/2$ is not cyclic.

Comment: Do you know if the first isomorphism still holds without choice?

Comment: I don't think that one needs full choice, but I am pretty sure that ZF is not enough. On the other hand, look at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/23202

Comment: Right, full choice probably has no chance of being needed here. I guess a more precise question would be if it is consistent with ZF that they are not isomorphic (Asaf probably knows, but obviously I cannot ping him here).

Comment: Yes, it is consistent (already mentioned by Asaf here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/302514 )

Comment: For (c) can we see that $S_4$ has only one subgroup of index $2$, but $S_3\times \mathbb Z_4$ has two?