# A question about the symbol $n$ in the additive group $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: group-theory, infinite-groups

As we know the symbol $n$ determines the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^n$ in the category of  vector spaces. Also, in the category of manifolds, $n$ determines the dimension of $n$-manifold $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Now, my question is that:

Is there any algebraic property related to the additive group $(\mathbb{R}^n ,+)$ which is  determined by $n$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/302514/are-mathbbr-and-mathbbc-isomorphic-as-additive-groups?rq=1) proves that as additive groups $\mathbb{R}^n \cong \mathbb{R}^m$ for all $n,m$.

Comment: As $K$-vector spaces even, for any countable subfield $K$ of $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti Thank you very much.

Comment: @Max This is a good point for me. Thank you so much.