# $\mathbb{R}$ is not a direct sum of its subgroups

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

How to prove the set of real numbers under addition; i.e., $(\mathbb{R}, +)$, is not the direct sum of two of its proper subgroups?

Comment: @  Seirios  I know a finite dimensional vs over infinite field can't be written as a union of finitely many of its proper subspaces,but R over Q is uncountable dimension!

Comment: Where is the problem? I don't understand your argument.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/302514/, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232568/isomorphism-between-mathbb-r2-and-mathbb-r?lq=1

Answer (score 7):

For me, your statement is false: $\mathbb{R}$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space of infinite dimension, so two proper subspaces $A,B$ may be found so that $\mathbb{R}= A \oplus B$. In particular, it gives a decomposition of $\mathbb{R}$ as an additive group.

Comment: the problem is about Z submodules of R,not Q submodules of R.Because subgroups of R may not be subspace of R (as vs over Q)

Comment: also you have to prove that it can not be written as a direct sum of its proper subgroups

Comment: @Via clearly any $\mathbb{Q}$-submodule will also be a $\mathbb{Z}$-submodule. It is clear from this answer that Seiros understood what you asked, but what you were asked to prove is not correct.

Comment: (well, assuming AC that is).

Comment: @  Tobias KildetoftCan you give me example of two non trivial proper subgroups of R whose direct sum is R

Comment: @Via Take a basis of $\mathbb{R}$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space. Take the subspace generated by one vector and the subspace generated by the rest of the vectors.

Comment: Yea I understand all of u are right..thank u