# $G \cong G \times H$ does not imply $H$ is trivial.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In Aluffi's *Algebra: Chapter $0$* there is a question asking to give a counterexample to the claim

> $G \cong G \times H$ implies $H$ is trivial.

I am looking for a hint.  Obviously, at least one of $G$ or $H$ needs to be infinite.  Doing something with $\mathbb{Z}$ seems to be the natural thing.  I tried showing $\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z} \times (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ by an ``interlacing evens and odds'' argument, but the "odd + odd" case killed my homomorphism...

Am I on the right track?

Thanks.

Comment: How about $ G $ group of finite sequences valued in $ \mathbb{Z} $, ie $ G = \oplus_{i = 0}^\infty \mathbb{Z} $  and $ H = \mathbb{Z} $.

Comment: Your idea doesn't work. $\mathbb Z \times (\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)$ has torsion, while $\mathbb Z$ does not.

Comment: @SDevalapurkar: How is $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ as an additive group?

Comment: @user174456:  You said finite sequences, but then your $G$ seems to consist of infinite sequences.

Comment: @DanDouglas note that this is the *direct sum*, which consists of sequences such that all but finitely elements are equal to zero.  That it, it is effectively the group of "terminating" sequences.

Comment: @DanDouglas in fact $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R\cong\Bbb R$ are isomorphic as *vector spaces* over $\Bbb Q$, not just as abelian groups. This is essentially because $\Bbb R$ has dimension $\frak c$ over $\Bbb Q$ and that $\frak c+c=c$. However we cannot write down such an isomorphism explicitly, because we invoke the axiom of choice to conclude it exists at all.

Comment: @anon: That is very interesting.  I like the answer to a similar question given here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/895428/can-r-times-r-be-isomorphic-to-r-as-rings

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/q/145163/92067 and its accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For an example, consider $G=\mathbb Z[x]$ as an additive group. Then $G\times \mathbb Z \cong G\times\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$ but $\mathbb Z\not\cong \mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$.

A key feature is the failure of one of the chain conditions. All of this can be found in exercises in Rotman, the chapter on Krull-Schmidt.

Comment: By $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ do you mean single variable polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Am I correct that your map looks like, as an example, $(x + 3, 2, 5) \mapsto (x^2 + 3x + 2, 5)$?

Comment: In fact, we could simply state $G \cong G \times \Bbb Z$

Comment: @DanDouglas Yes to both.

Comment: oh I see, and this is the same as user174456 's idea above

Comment: @DanDouglas Yep.