# $H \cong K \times H$ implies $K$ is trivial?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H$, $K$ be groups, and suppose that $H \cong K \times H$. Does it necessarily follow that $K$ is trivial?

Comment: After answering I noticed that this duplicates at least two earlier questions; the other one that I found is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/925809/g-cong-g-times-h-does-not-imply-h-is-trivial?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

No: let $K$ be any group, and let $H$ be the Cartesian product of infinitely many copies of $K$.

Answer (score 1):

No, there are some pretty weird spaces out there that satisfy things like $$ H\equiv H\oplus H$$ For example the sequence space $\ell^2$ (taken as an additive group) can be written as a direct sum of itself twice. You just interleaved even and odd indexes.