# Can we find a surjective function from $N$ to Q/{0} such that $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I tried a proof by contradiction, but I don't know how to proceed it using the theorems

Comment: Hint: such a function does actually exist.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

Let's try to construct it by thinking what happens to the first few natural numbers:

- Putting $y=1$: $f(x\times 1)=f(x)\times f(1)$, but $f(x\times 1)=f(x)$, so $f(x)=f(x)\times f(1)$, which means $f(1)=1$.
- What about $y=2$? $f(x\times 2)=f(x)\times f(2)$ but we have no more information, so the choice of $f(2)$ is free so far. However, this determines the value of $f(2^n)$: $f(4)=f(2)\times f(2)$ which is fixed, then (edit) $f(8)=f(4)\times f(2)$ which are both fixed... By induction we define the values of $f(2^n)$.
- $y=3$. $f(x\times 3)=f(x)\times f(3)$, and the choice of $f(3)$ is again free. Just as before, this defines the values for all the powers of 3, $f(3^n)$. However, we also have defined the values of numbers whose only prime factors are $2$ and $3$. For instance, $f(6)=f(2)\times f(3)$ is fixed, and then $f(12)=f(2)\times f(6)$ and $f(18)=f(3)\times f(6)$ are fixed...
- Generalising, we only have the freedom to define the values of $f(p)$ where $p$ is a prime. $f(1)=1$ and $f(n)$ for $n$ a composite number depends on the values of $f(p_1), f(p_2),\dots$, where $p_1, p_2, \dots$ are the prime factors of $n$.

This is enough. There are infinitely many prime numbers, therefore the set $\mathbb{P}$ of all primes is countably infinite. The set $\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}$ is also countable, and therefore we can find a bijection between $\mathbb{P}$ and $\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}$. Now define $f(1)=1$, and define $f(p)$ for $p$ prime using the bijection. This makes $f$ surjective (it hits each  point of $\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}$ at least once), and well-defined since the values $f(n)$ for $n$ composite are fully specified.

Comment: "$f(6)=f(4)\times f(2)$..." Of course, you meant $f(8)$, not $f(6)$.

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Comment: Good news, you don't need to construct the bijection at all. The *definition* of two sets having the same size (cardinality) is that there exists a bijection between them, see for instance https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1359905/does-same-cardinality-imply-a-bijection . So, as soon as two sets are countable, you get the existence of a bijection for free.