# Does injectivity and equal cardinality imply a bijection?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

EDIT: G is finite.

Let $G$ be a group and $g\in G$. I'm trying to show that the function $\phi_g :G\rightarrow G$ defined by $\phi_g (x)=gxg^{-1}$ for every $x\in G$ is a bijection.

I've shown that $\phi_g$ is injective. Does injectivity along with equal cardinality imply surjectivity and hence a bijection?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1359905/does-same-cardinality-imply-a-bijection

Comment: Are you assuming that $G$ is finite?  If so, injective does imply surjective.  If not, then it doesn't.

Comment: Still, a direct proof...given $y\in G$ can you find an $x$ such that $\phi_g(x)=y$?

Comment: Really not difficult.  We want $gxg^{-1}=y$.  How can we solve that for $x$?

Comment: With your edit, the answer is yes. The image is a subset of $G$ with the same cardinality as $G$, so it must equal $G$.

Answer (score 3):

No, you do not have such an implication. For instance, in the group $\Bbb Z$ with addition, the homomorphism given by multiplication by $2$ is injective and equal cardinality, but it is not a bijection.

In this case, I would rather try to find an explicit inverse (i.e. guess what the inverse of $\phi_g$ *ought* to be, then show that that is indeed an inverse).

**Responding to the edit:** If $G$ is finite, then *any* injection (homomorphism or not) is indeed a bijection.

Answer (score 0):

The right answer, I think, has been given by lulu above. We do not need the edit that $G$ is finite to show that the map $\phi_g$ is bijective. It is injective and certainly surjective, since $gxg^{-1}=y$ implies that $x=g^{-1}yg$.
Of course, if one does not see this, one can ask if injectivity is enough. This is not the case in general as Arthur has pointed out.

More generally, $\phi_g$ is an inner automorphism of $G$ for all $g\in G$.