# Multiple vector space structures on $\mathbb{F}^n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, vector-spaces

When it comes to the $\mathbb{F}$-vector space $\mathbb{F}^n$, it's very natural to assume $\mathbb{F}$ acts by scalar multiplication. But if the set Hom$_\textbf{Ring}(\mathbb{F})$ has more than one element, $\mathbb{F}$ has multiple ways to act on $\mathbb{F}^n$. For example, the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{25}$. Consider $\mathbb{F}_{25}$ as a 1-dimensional $\mathbb{F}_{25}$ vector space. Then the following, essentially pre-composing the usual scalar multiplication with a Frobenius map, also gives a vector space structure:
$$a\cdot x:=a^5x$$
My confusion is that I haven't really heard of people talking about other vector space structures than the usual one. Do they have any importance mathematically?

There is a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1479587/vector-space-structures-over-mathbbr). My question is more of reference-requesting. Any guidance will be appreciated.